# Background music starts when relaunch

Tags: android, eclipse, media-player

I used MediaPlayer in creating background music in my menu game. it seems to work correctly but when I start another activity then going back on menu. the sounds disappear. how can I play it again whenever the menu activity launch?

heres some of my codes:

```
logoMusic = MediaPlayer.create(NewMainActivity.this, R.raw.onepiece_sound);
logoMusic.start();
```

then on my pause method:

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    logoMusic.release();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `onRestart` method for that.

```
     @Override
        protected void onRestart() {
            super.onPause();

            logoMusic = MediaPlayer.create(NewMainActivity.this, R.raw.onepiece_sound);
            logoMusic.start();
        }
```

This will be called only when you go back to the activity, not when you open it for the first time.

Comment: thank you sir. one more question sir. how can i loop it back when the music ends>